# how to provide a callback redirect URI in API callout to invoke LWC in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, oauth2, experience-cloud

I am making a callout to Spotify `/authorize` endpoint where it requires a redirect URI to redirect the user to, to approve the access that salesforce needs.

After user approves, Spotify redirects the user to that callback URL which is where I need to invoke another callout to get OAuth Token using the code received in earlier request.

- REST GET Callout to Spotify /authorize (send redirect URI as part of request)
- Spotify takes user to approve the access being requested
- Once User approves, spotify send user to the redirect URL with code

I need to redirect User back to the salesforce console app instead of experience site with the authorization code, how can I achieve that? Below is my current solution.

**Current solution:**

I created an experience site and gave that URL as redirect URI, the problem is User is navigated to the experience site and can't be navigated back to Salesforce after they approve spotify authorize.

By doing this, user's workflow completely shift to the experience cloud now instead of within salesforce.

Is there another way to give a redirect URI and keep the user within Salesforce when redirected by spotify?

Comment: This is what I've been wanting to do but wasn't sure it would work, glad to hear it worked for you. Why can't you just return a RestResponse from your api that sets redirect back to where you want ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm

Comment: I didnt make much progress after this because I wasn't able to solve for the above, I wanted a simple callback to Salesforce console where I can invoke the OAuth token callout.